# Запись в ячейку с типом date

Tags: php, postgresql, дата

Пытаюсь записать дату в ячейку

```
$request  = "INSERT INTO request(id_user, number_pasport, serial_pasport, region, birthday, date_pasport, 
            name, surname, thirdname, status, id_report) VALUES ($client[4], $number, $serial, $region, $date_r, $date_p, '$name', '$surname', '$patr', 0, 2)";
$res = pg_query($dbconn, $request);
```

ругается:

> Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  column "birthday" is of
>   type date but expression is of type integer LINE 2: ..., status,
>   id_report) VALUES (5, 499227, 1216, 33, 1996-08-08...
>                                                                ^

Пробовал разные варианты маски, но результат один и тот же

```
$birthday = '1999-01-01';
$birthday = '19990108';
```

Comment: не уверен, но, возможно, нужны скобки - '$date_r'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типом `date` принимается в частности формат YYYY-MM-DD.

Но не числовое выражение 1999-01-01, т.е. число 1997. Это не дата. Это вычисление целочисленное. Сравните два запроса:

```
insert into tablename (datefield) values (1999-01-01);
insert into tablename (datefield) values ('1999-01-01');
```

Первый не является вставкой даты, т.к. после вычисления *выражения* получится число, второй - является.

Comment: да, оказалось банально. Забыл кавычки.